# struts2, code completion in jsp

Tags: jsf, netbeans, struts2, code-completion

I have done some work with *JSF*(using netbeans as the *IDE*) and within your *jsp/xhtml* file you get code on *beans/resource* bundles that your have defined.

*ATM* I am investigating *struts2* and seem to be unable to get similar functionality in the *IDE*. Is this just the case with the *IDE* or do I need to define something?

Thanks

Comment: you really need to elaborate what exactly you are looking

Answer (score 0):

So, you basically just want a [Struts plugin for Netbeans](http://www.google.com/search?q=struts+plugin+for+netbeans)? As the link reveals, there are several, even that there's already one [built-in in Netbeans 6.7 or newer](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps-struts.html).

Comment: I did install a netbeans struts2 plugin from java.net. From what I see it basically is just quick way to create a struts2 web project with the libs and web.xml.

Comment: And it didn't satisfy? Then you really need to elaborate more what functionaly you actually need.